# I can not access my server by its name

Tags: ip, nameserver

I have a domain called spdserver.com I can access its control panel using IP but using "spdserver.com" doesn't work. I thought it would be name server issue but I checked my Name.com account and everything is right.

Even when I check who.is to see if my IP and name servers are matching together. Did I forget anything? I want your help just to know if I should check anything else?

Comment: Does your hoster say you should be able to access it by domain name

Comment: It was working somedays ago but it stops now

Comment: Alright, what error does it give you then?

Comment: ok. I tried to ping it and it gave a timed out and I tried to nslookup the domain name and it gave a wrong IP. how does that happend?

Comment: Something changed the IP, did you move hosting?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your DNS entries are not complete.  You do not have an A record with an IP address.

Currently, its:

```
$ dig spdserver.com

; <<>> DiG 9.4.1 <<>> spdserver.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 1125
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;spdserver.com.                 IN      A
```

The "A" record should look something like this, where 10.1.1.1 is your >static< ip address.  If you are using dynamic IP, you may need to play some games with crecords (CNAME)

```
 spdserver.com.                 IN      A  10.1.1.1
```

Once your DNS entries are updated, give it time to propogate this depends on TTL attributes in DNS.